# Is it possible to solve: xa = 4200, xb = 4410, ya=4000, yb = 4200 for x, y, a and b?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm in a little bit of a pickle here, can someone tell me if it is actually possible to solve these? From the general rule of thumb, 4 variables, 4 equations should be able to right?

Comment: Mosquito-nuking solution: the Jacobian determinant for this system of equations is zero, so no.

Comment: @Rainbow: offhand question, have you taken up calculus already? The "nuke" solution becomes less of a "nuke" if you have a lot of simultaneous equations.

Comment: Spuh, ganinda fanoophyhoffy.

Answer (score 1):

The best you can do is $20x = 21y$ and $21a = 20b.$
If you write your second pair of equations as
$$a \left( \frac{20}{21} x \right) = 4000,$$
$$b \left( \frac{20}{21} x \right) = 4200$$
we note that they are equivalent to your first pair
$$ax = 4200$$
$$bx = 4410,$$
simply by multipling up by the $20/21.$

As for your general rule of thumb, note that a system of equations
can be [inconsistent.](http://www.mathwords.com/i/inconsistent_system_of_equations.htm)

Comment: What if I can introduce more equations? Such as xc = 420, yc = 400? Or will it never satisfy?

Comment: @RainbowTheory Again, they give $20x=21y,$ and $c$ can be any value not equal to $0$.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your help Derek.